# System.Diagnostics.Trace ignores culture settings

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, formatting, cultureinfo

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "$";
decimal value = 500;
Trace.TraceInformation("{0:C}", value);
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("{0:C}", value));
```

produces the following output:

```
Information: 0 : ¤500.00
Information: 0 : 500,00$
```

That means it either performs formatting on a different thread or ignores `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` (probably replacing it with invariant one). WHY?? [MSDN keeps silence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2xfhcy.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, `Trace` output explicitly uses `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Decompiled source for `TraceListener.TraceEvent` has it this way:

```
this.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args));
```

You already provided a workaround: format for any culture you want at the call site.